# Need to convert text box from table when user will click on update button in AngularjS

Tags: html, angularjs

I have created one table in HTML using AngularJS .Table's data is getting populated from back end service. Please find the below code for table generation:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Contract Number</td>
<td>Order Number</td>
<td>Shipment Number</td>
<td>Shipment Control No</td>
<td>Status Code</td>
<td>Source System</td>
<td>Destination System</td>
<td>RFID</td>
<td>UID</td>
<td>Want to Update ?</td>
<td>Want to delete ?</td>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat="x in ContractParentChildData">
<td>{{x.Contract_Number}}</td>
<td>{{x.Order_Number}}</td>
<td>{{x.Shipment_Number}}</td>
<td>{{x.Shipment_Control_No}}</td>
<td>{{x.Status_Code}}</td>
<td>{{x.Source_System}}</td>
<td>{{x.Destination_System}}</td>
<td>{{x.RFID}}</td>
<td>{{x.UID}}</td>
<td>
 <button ng-show="mode != 'edit'" ng-click="mode = 'edit'; updateShipment($index)">Update</button>
 <button ng-show="mode == 'edit'" ng-click="mode = null; saveShipment()">Save</button>
</td>
<td><button ng-click="deleteEmployee(x.Contract_Number)">Delete</button></td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Please find below picture for output:
[image]

My Requirement is when User will click on "update button" for a particular row, that Row should be converted as text box with previous data and when user will click on "save" button, textbox should be converted to table's row with updated values.

I have tried to search in google, no satisfactory answer I have got till now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this type of functionality you need [angular-xeditable](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-form)

Html

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
 <form editable-form name="editableForm" onaftersave="saveUser()">
    <div>
      <!-- editable username (text with validation) -->
      <span class="title">User name: </span>
      <span editable-text="user.name" e-name="name" onbeforesave="checkName($data)" e-required>{{ user.name || 'empty' }}</span>
    </div> 

    <div>
      <!-- editable status (select-local) -->
      <span class="title">Status: </span>
      <span editable-select="user.status" e-name="status" e-ng-options="s.value as s.text for s in statuses">
        {{ (statuses | filter:{value: user.status})[0].text || 'Not set' }}
      </span>
    </div>  

    <div>
      <!-- editable group (select-remote) -->
      <span class="title">Group: </span>
      <span editable-select="user.group" e-name="group" onshow="loadGroups()" e-ng-options="g.id as g.text for g in groups">
        {{ showGroup() }}
      </span>
    </div>

    <div>
      <!-- button to show form -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="editableForm.$show()" ng-show="!editableForm.$visible">
        Edit
      </button>
      <!-- buttons to submit / cancel form -->
      <span ng-show="editableForm.$visible">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="editableForm.$waiting">
          Save
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="editableForm.$waiting" ng-click="editableForm.$cancel()">
          Cancel
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </form>  
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable", "ngMockE2E"]);

app.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $filter, $http) {
 $scope.user = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'awesome user',
    status: 2,
    group: 4,
    groupName: 'admin'
  }; 

  $scope.statuses = [
    {value: 1, text: 'status1'},
    {value: 2, text: 'status2'},
    {value: 3, text: 'status3'},
    {value: 4, text: 'status4'}
  ]; 

  $scope.groups = [];
  $scope.loadGroups = function() {
    return $scope.groups.length ? null : $http.get('/groups').success(function(data) {
      $scope.groups = data;
    });
  };

  $scope.showGroup = function() {
    if($scope.groups.length) {
      var selected = $filter('filter')($scope.groups, {id: $scope.user.group});
      return selected.length ? selected[0].text : 'Not set';
    } else {
      return $scope.user.groupName;
    }
  };

  $scope.checkName = function(data) {
    if (data !== 'awesome' && data !== 'error') {
      return "Username should be `awesome` or `error`";
    }
  };

  $scope.saveUser = function() {
    // $scope.user already updated!
    return $http.post('/saveUser', $scope.user).error(function(err) {
      if(err.field && err.msg) {
        // err like {field: "name", msg: "Server-side error for this username!"} 
        $scope.editableForm.$setError(err.field, err.msg);
      } else { 
        // unknown error
        $scope.editableForm.$setError('name', 'Unknown error!');
      }
    });
  };
});

// ---------------- mock $http requests --------------------
app.run(function($httpBackend) {
  $httpBackend.whenGET('/groups').respond([
    {id: 1, text: 'user'},
    {id: 2, text: 'customer'},
    {id: 3, text: 'vip'},
    {id: 4, text: 'admin'}
  ]);

  $httpBackend.whenPOST(/\/saveUser/).respond(function(method, url, data) {
    data = angular.fromJson(data);
    if(data.name === 'error') {
      return [500, {field: 'name', msg: 'Server-side error for this username!'}]; 
    } else {
      return [200, {status: 'ok'}]; 
    }
  });
});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/81/) for example